# How to stop ASIWebPageRequest from caching 404 html?

Tags: ios, http-status-code-404, asihttprequest

I have an app with multiple UIWebViews to show some web pages and I'm using ASIWebPageRequest to make it work offline. Problem is, when I get 404 from server, it gets into cache and if next time I'm using the app offline, I'm of course seeing the 404 html, not the last "legit" page content. Same goes for error 500, is there any known workaround for this problem? I just want the app to ignore all error htmls and load the last html with the "good" content.

Comment: are you saving a cache of the page yourself?

Comment: No, I'm just using ASIWebPageRequest to do this for me.

Comment: does ASIWebPageRequest allow you to give a name to each of the pages you save

Comment: Yes and no, it downloads html and all resources and stores them locally on disc. The directory depends just on the url of the request, so I have each page separately but I can't cache 2 different versions of the same page.
I believe this question requires some knowledge of the ASIWebPageRequest, since best solution is probably to edit the code of this class.

Comment: There might be a workaround if you use one of the tinyurl pages? You could have two different links that point to the same website

Comment: That probably could be done, but it's not really optimal solution since my app would have to store twice the normal amount of data (including heavy images), I'm trying to find a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: he best way to fix this is to check what is the status code which you have received. If you have received error 404 then then best thing to do is to clear cache.

Comment: But is there a way to detect 404 before ASIWebPageRequest overwrites the previously cached data?